# ADFS Custom claims Rule - Send AD Information and IP address in the claim

Tags: adfs, adfs4.0

How do you send AD attributes along with the IP address of the computer in a claim for ADFS?  The following code does not work.

```
c1:[Type == "http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/claims/windowsaccountname", Issuer == "AD AUTHORITY"]
 => issue(store = "Active Directory", types = ("http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/givenname", "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/surname", "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/emailaddress", "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/name", "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/nameidentifier"), query = ";givenName,sn,mail,userPrincipalName,mail;{0}", param = c1.Value);
&& c2:[Type == "http://schemas.microsoft.com/2012/01/requestcontext/claims/x-ms-forwarded-client-ip"]
 => issue(claim = c2);
```